# How to access an array with specific numbers in mips

Tags: arrays, mips

i have this array

```
picture: .word 0x000007c, 0x00000fe,0x00000fe,0x000005e,0x00000fe, 0x000007e,0x000003c,0x0000018, 0x0001ffc,0x0003ffe,0x000303f,0x000143f, 0x0001c3f,0x000083f,0x000083f,0x008083f,0x00f081f,0x00d9c1f,0x00f943f, 0x18f007e,0x11e00fc,0x13f01ec,0x1ff81ff,0x0ff81ff,0x0fcc003,0x070000d, 0x060000c,0x060000c,0x060000c,0x030001c
```

I write

```
la $s0, picture   
lw $s0, 0($s0)
```

and I get the first element, but when I write

```
lw $s1, 32($s0)
```

or

```
lw $s1, 36($s0)
```

I can't get 8th or 9th element and I get another numbers which are no related to the numbers in picture (maybe because I use all 32 bytes of register)
What can I do ?

Comment: You overwrote the value of `$s0` by loading the first element into `$s0`

Comment: It doesn't matter if you overwrite the value into $s0, its the same thing, this is a way not to use a lot of registers if you have to write big program and you need many registers. I thing I found the solution, I confused with values in registers and I consider that results were wrong.

Comment: It does matter that you overwrite `$s0` if you then go and try to load from that address again.

Comment: I don't have problem with the values I get, I  solve it but it wasn't to how I load the value of $s0